# How to Display Data Inside Nested ng-repeat Directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two objects, programme and section, each programme has some sections
I have two services, the first service shows all programmes, and the second service shows all sections for one programme, the problem is : I can't show each sections for one programme using the code of programme as a parameter, this is my code :

```
var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("myController",function($scope,$http){

    $scope.programme=null;
    $scope.section=null;

   $http.get("/programmes").success(function(response) {
        $scope.programme = response;
    });


    //getting sections for one programme using code
   $scope.getSectionByCode = function(code)
    {   
       $http.get("/listsections/"+code).success(function(data){

          $scope.section = data;
       });
    }; 

});
```

HTML

```
<div class="padd" ng-app="myApp" 
                  ng-controller="myController">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in programme" 
            ng-init="getSectionByProgCode(x.code)" >
                {{x.titre}}
            <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="s in section">{{s.title }}</li>
            </ul>
        </li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
```

**the result of this code is :**  
programme 1
 
          Section title  4 
          Section title  5 
programme 2 
          Section title  4 
          Section title  5

**but im looking for this result :** 
programme 1
 
          Section title 1 
          Section title  2 
          Section title  3 
programme 2 
          Section title 4 
          Section title  5

Note : when I check my browser log, I find that the service of section get the results properly for each programme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all I would advise you to read about how to structure your app properly, e.g. place http calls in services, store data in services, etc.

Now - your problem is that you do 2 asynchronous calls and place both results on the same variable: `$scope.section`, so obviously both `ng-repeat` divs will show the same data.

One way to fix that is you could make the `$scope.section` variable an array and store by index:

```
ng-init="getSectionByProgCode(x.code, $index)"
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.section = [];

$scope.getSectionByCode = function(code, index)
{   
   $http.get("/listsections/"+code).success(function(data){

      $scope.section[index] = data;
   });
};
```

HTML function name and controller function name don't match, I'm guessing it's a typo of yours.

A different way to solve it **(preferable by me and fellow commentators)**, is to store your section data under the programme itself:

```
<li ng-repeat="x in programme" 
       ng-init="getSectionByProgCode(x)" >
              {{x.titre}}
     <ul>
         <li ng-repeat="s in x.section">{{s.title}}</li>
     </ul>
</li>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.getSectionByProgCode = function(programme)
{   
    $http.get("/listsections/" + programme.code).success(function(data){

        programme.section = data;
    });
 };
```

Comment: Bah beat me to it, OR when you get programmes you could fetch the section data at that point and create one object!

Comment: I think it would be better if we bind section to `x` object itself..rather than having it `$index` based, like `ng-init="getSectionByProgCode(x)"` then function will be `$scope.getSectionByCode = function(x)
{ $http.get("/listsections/"+x.code).success(function(data)  x.section[index] = data;
   });
};`, what are your thoughts on it?

Comment: I agree with you both, added that in an edit after my first approach. Personally I like to attach that data to the first object.

Comment: hey @Omri , thank you very much for your response, i try your first suggestion , this is the result http://recordit.co/G7W1dtwOYY   and this is the code :     $scope.getSectionByCode = function(code,index)
 {
       $http.get("/listsections/"+code).success(function(data){
       $scope.section[index] = data; 

       });
    }; 
               <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="p in programme" ng-init="getSectionByCode(p.progCode,$index)" > {{p.titre}}<ul>
                          <li ng-repeat="s in section">{{s.titre}}</li> </ul></li>  </ul>

Comment: @Ali Yes, sorry, that's because the HTML needs some adjustment as well to read from section[$index] (the first index not the second). Try my second approach, it's better.

Comment: thank you so much @Omri   i  get what i want ,using your  second suggestion , thank you man (y)

Comment: @Ali No problem :) If this answer helped you, please check the "check mark" icon to the left of it so other users will know you found your solution.

Comment: @Omri Done, please do you have some links, about how to structure my angular application properly?

Comment: @Ali Not anything specific. Google "angular JS best practices" and you're bound to get there.